# Connect to Azure SQL Server via Linux + ODBC + Active Directory Authentication

Tags: sql-server, odbc, azure-active-directory, freetds, unixodbc

I'm attempting to connect to **Azure SQL Server 2017** from **Debian 8 or 9**. Our SQL Server instance is connected to our Active Directory **requiring Active Directory Authentication.**

Thus far, I've tried connecting using the [Microsoft ODBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) in conjunction with [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) to no avail.

Recent attempts with [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) haven't worked well either. Errors vary but typically result in server timeouts or being unable to connect to the server altogether.

Are there recommended best practices for making this connection with these constraints?

**Here is the recommended connection string for the database in question:**

`Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:xxxx.windows.net,1433;Database=xxxx;Uid={your_user_name};Pwd={your_password_here};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword`

Primarily, I'm unsure about how to configure `odbc.ini`,`odbcinst.ini` and `freetds.conf` to accommodate this connection string.

Details:

- FreeTDS Version = `7.4`
- FreeTDS Protocol = `1.00.92`
- MS ODBC Driver Version = `13.1`

Comment: [Documentation of Microsoft driver DSN/connect-string keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/dsn-connection-string-attribute?view=sql-server-2017)?  [Documentation for troubleshooting Microsoft driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#troubleshooting-connection-problems)?

Comment: With FreeTDS, have you tried connecting with `tsql` from the command line to make sure you have everything right? `TDSVER=7.4 tsql -H servername.database.windows.net -U "DOMAIN\\username" -D databasename -p 1433 -P password` If you're on a domain, you need the double backslash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398646/how-do-i-connect-to-azure-using-unixodbc-and-freetds

Comment: @FlipperPA Yes, I just tried what you suggested and received the following: `Adaptive Server connection failed` with little else to go on. `Error 20002`